# Show the derived subgroup is the centre of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I've been asked to show that if $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^3$, then the derived or commutator subgroup is equal to the centre, $G'$=$Z(G)$.
I know that since $G'$ is a subgroup of $G$, it must have order $1$, $p$, $p^2$ or $p^3$. If I can show that |$G'$| = $p^2$, then it is abelian and a maximal proper subgroup, so it must be the centre of $G$. However I'm unsure of how to go about proving this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a theorem which says the following: if $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ where $G/N$ is abelian, then $G' \subseteq N$. Since $|G/Z(G)| = p^2$, it follows that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, that is, $G' \subseteq Z(G)$. Since $G'$ is not trivial and $|Z(G)| = p$, it follows $G' = Z(G)$. Understandable?

Answer (score 1):

The fact you need to use is that in a non-abelian group, $G/Z(G)$ is not cyclic.

I will leave you to (a) prove this fact and (b) work out how to apply it.